# "There has been an error processing your request" in installing Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, installation

> There has been an error processing your request
>
> ```
> Error in file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\sql\cms_setup\install-1.6.0.0.php" - SQLSTATE[42501]: Base table or view a
>   `block_id` smallint NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'Block ID' ,
>   `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Block Title' ,
>   `identifier` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Block String Identifier' ,
>   `content` mediumtext NULL COMMENT 'Block Content' ,
>   `creation_time` timestamp NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Block Creation Time' ,
>   `update_time` timestamp NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Block Modification Time' ,
>   `is_active` smallint NOT NULL default '1' COMMENT 'Is Block Active' ,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`block_id`)
> } COMMENT='CMS Block Table' ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
> ```

[image]

Comment: Check with https://community.magento.com/t5/Technical-Issues/SQLSTATE-42S02-Base-table-or-view-not-found-1146/m-p/14242#M657

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that Magento tries to create a table which already exists. This takes place in an upgrade script and was probably caused by an incomplete previous run of said upgrade script. Magento executes upgrade scripts, but only marks them done when they complete without error. Even an incompletely run script can have created tables, though, and next time Magento tries to run that update script the exstance of those tables cause a problem.

So you can either do some Database work and do some tweeking like removing the tables in question (with saving the data if needed), or you redo your Magento Installation.

This can also be caused by recently installed extensions, if so uninstalling them with the Connect Manager and reinstalling them might work.

Answer (score 1):

once I have same problem because I have installed theme sql first and theme sql is old and not compatible with my current version of magento,

So I have solve this error by following step.

open your database go to `core_resource` tabel and in this entry `admin_setup` change `version` and `data version` to `1.6.1.2` for both value.

hope this will help you

Comment: bhayya this will not be work for me.same error will be occred.any suggesion for it.